# Maven archetype error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have installed eclipse neon 64 bit on windows 7 enterprise. I am trying to create a maven project but everytime i am receiving an error--{ Could not resolve archetype from any of the configured repositories}--. I have checked the settings.xml file and added catalog too but still cant get rid of this error. any suggestions.
Thanks.[This is the error image in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CETKz.png)

Comment: Did you add http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml ?

Comment: yep i have added that

Answer (score 0):

You could create it using command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app 
    -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
```

And then import into the Eclipse using File -> Import -> Existing Maven Project. The result will be the same.

Comment: thanks but when i type the command mvn-version in cmd it is showing that mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command. I have extracted the zip file and added the path to the environment variables and created M2_home too even though it is showing an error. any suggestions.

Comment: Make sure your `%M2_home%\bin` is on the `%PATH%`

Comment: i have configured this one too. but even then it is showing the error

Comment: Make sure you've restarted your command prompt after changing the path